# Neglecting Empty Boxes: SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I have a database of one table that has 8 columns.
I also have a search page in my website with 8 text boxes (that corresponds to the 8 columns in the database) where the user can enter some values to retrieve the data with the specified conditions.

If I use the AND operator in the SQL query, then the user have to specify constraints for all the 8 boxes.

What I want to do is to apply the AND operator for the boxes where the user entered some values and neglect the other empty boxes.. any idea how can I do this?

I am using the GUI of dreamweaver, and the code is attached.
Thanks!

```
<?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
        function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") {
            if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
                $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
            }

            $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

            switch ($theType) {
                case "text":
                    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                    break;    
                case "long":
                case "int":
                    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                    break;
                case "double":
                    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                    break;
                case "date":
                    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                    break;
                case "defined":
                    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                    break;
            }

            return $theValue;
        }
    }

    $varID_Recordset1 = "0";
    if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
        $varID_Recordset1 = $_GET['ID'];
    }

    $varFirstName_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['First_Name'])) {
        $varFirstName_Recordset1 = $_GET['First_Name'];
    }

    $varLastName_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET[Last_Name'])) {
        $varLastName_Recordset1 = $_GET[Last_Name'];
    }

    $varCGPA_Recordset1 = "0.00";
    if (isset($_GET['GPA'])) {
        $varCGPA_Recordset1 = $_GET['GPA'];
    }

    $varGender_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['Gender'])) {
        $varGender_Recordset1 = $_GET['Gender'];
    }

    $varNationality_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['Nationality'])) {
        $varNationality_Recordset1 = $_GET['Nationality'];
    }

    $varAdvisor_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['Advisor'])) {
        $varAdvisor_Recordset1 = $_GET['Advisor'];
    }

    $varEnroll_Recordset1 = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['Enrollment_Year])) {
        $varEnroll_Recordset1 = $_GET['Enrollment_Year];
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
    $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT students.ID, students.FirstName, students.LastName FROM students WHERE ID= %s AND FirstName= %s AND LastName=%s AND GPA=%s AND Gender = %s AND Nationality= %s AND Advisor= %s AND EnrollmentYear= %s", GetSQLValueString($varID_Recordset1, "int"),GetSQLValueString($varFirstName_Recordset1, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varLastName_Recordset1, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varCGPA_Recordset1, "double"),GetSQLValueString($varGender_Recordset1, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varNationality_Recordset1, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varAdvisor_Recordset1, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varEnroll_Recordset1, "int"));
    $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $databasestudents) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
    $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged the errors first ?

Comment: Also see about sql injection, prepared statements and PDO/mysqli as opposed to your deprecated method (mysql_)